# Feedback for logo

Tags: logo, critique, branding

I would appreciate some feedback for a fictional l brand I devised. so basically, the company creates fresh, authentic Italian food for people who are looking for something quick to eat, but aren't willing to sacrifice quality. Therefore, I'm aiming for a logo that gives a real rustic and homely feel when viewed.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: There's an apostrophe missing.

Comment: Moreover, heartland has specific connotations - especially to someone with some knowledge of Italy - is this food specifically Tuscan style? What makes this restaurant the "heartland" of Italy, versus you know, the actual Italian heartland? "Food *from* the Italian heartland" maybe, but as written it seems as though you are saying this restaurant IS the heartland of Italy proper - which seems like a grandiloquent claim a priori. Secondarily, though you have a slight touch of Italian flag colours, the only other symbolic or graphic element you have to tie to "Italian" is a wooden spoon...

Answer (score 1):

Despite the scarce information in the question about the concept and the total absence of the logo realization process, it presents some formal details that may need solution.

- The combination of a calligraphic font with an italic is never recommended, since it's nearly impossible to find two different families fonts with the same directional axis. On the contrary, the contrast with a normal regular font is preferable.

[image: angles]

- In addition to the two fonts, there are two other different graphic styles. Four elements to unify in a logo. This added to four formally different elements harms his visual unity.

[image]

- Added to the double typographies directionality, the white of the Italian flag is interpreted as a space, which causes each of the color strokes tend to escape the limits of the logo, again disadvantaging the formal unity

[image: Unity]

Personally I think that there are four elements placed in a random way without any sense, which makes it difficult to try to create a unique image, a logo. So the only vertical alignment axes are the left and right edge, the rest is chaos, no vertical axis matches.

[image: vertical axis]

My recommendation, organize everything, not only the conceptual but also the formal elements and study in depth if what you have resolved conceptually is reflected visually.
Being the designer or the owner of the company, imagine that someone accuses you of plagiarism and you must defend this logo in a court describing each of the points you wanted to represent when creating it:

[image: logo]

It's not about finding a graphical solution for each point, but at the level that is now, the judge will only clearly see *Italy* and *Food*. Maybe he will ask:

1. It's *quality* a British calligraphic wedding font?
2. It's *rustic* an imperceptible graphic treatment?
3. It's *home feel* a bad made pictogram of a wooden spoon?

Answer (score 0):

I don't find it rustic or homely. 
Looks to me like you wen't more for elegant.

I also think you're trying to put to much into it. I realize it's a flag, but the white sort of melts into the background so it just looks like two colored rectangles on each side. Add to that the spoon and the slogan, I think it's a bit too much for a logo. 
I would take away either the spoon and center the slogan or take away the flag.
A logo needs to be more cohesive, like one solid thing.

Also Scott's right, there should be an apostrophe in "Nonna's".